# В программе по заказу мороженого надо создать Label с ценой к продукту, она должна меняться в зависимости от текущего выбора продуктов в мороженом

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Я хочу создать так называемый "Конструктор мороженого" как в некоторых программах доставки. Для такого надо создать "ценник" который будет меняться в зависимости от того что выбрал пользователь пломбир или же ванильное мороженое. Проблема в том, что у меня идёт выбор не только типа мороженого, но и добавок к нему, а также с каким вкусом оно будет. Вот код того что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class IceCreamController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    public ChoiceBox<String> IceCreamFlavor;

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> IceCreamType;

    @FXML
    public CheckBox S1, S2, S3;

    @FXML
    public Button ToOrder;

    @FXML
    public ListView<String> Orders;

    @FXML
    public Label Price;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        //Виды и вкусы мороженого
        IceCreamType.getItems().addAll("Пломбир", "Шоколадное", "Ванильное");
        IceCreamFlavor.getItems().addAll("Яблочный", "Банановый", "Клубничный", "Апельсиновый", "Грушевый");

        //Выбор вкуса и вида мороженого


        IceCreamType.setOnAction(event -> getPriceForType());

        IceCreamFlavor.setOnAction(event -> getPriceForFlavor());

        //Выбор добавок
        String Supplements = "";
        if(S1.isSelected()) Supplements += "Шококлад ";
        if(S2.isSelected()) Supplements += "Орехи ";
        if(S3.isSelected()) Supplements += "Джем ";
        if(Supplements.equals("")) Supplements += "Нет ";
        String finalSupplements = Supplements;

        //Помещение заказа в историю
        ToOrder.setOnAction(actionEvent -> Orders.getItems().addAll("Мороженое: " + IceCreamType.getValue() + "; Вкус: " + IceCreamFlavor.getValue() + "; Добавки: " + finalSupplements));
    }

    public void setText(int price)
    {
        Price.setText(String.valueOf(price));
    }

    public void getPriceForType ()
    {
        //Цена вида мороженого
        int price = 0;
        if(IceCreamType.getValue().equals("Пломбир") || IceCreamType.getValue().equals("Шоколадное")){
            price = 14;
        }else {
            price = 10;
        }
        setText(price);
    }

    public void getPriceForFlavor ()
    {
        //Цена за вкусы мороженого
        int price = 0;
        if (IceCreamFlavor.getValue().equals("Яблочный") || IceCreamFlavor.getValue().equals("Банановый")) price += 5;
        else price += 7;
        Price.setText(String.valueOf(price));
    }
    public void getPriceForSupplements ()
    {
        int price = 0;

        //Цена за добавки к мороженому
        if(S1.isSelected()) price += 4;
        if(S2.isSelected()) price += 2;
        if(S3.isSelected()) price += 5;
        Price.setText(String.valueOf(price));
   }
}
```

Мне хотелось бы чтоб цена менялась после каждого выбора продукта соответственно. Можете ли дать совет как это грамотно реализовать?
Если нужен fxml файл то вот он:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="247.0" prefWidth="443.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.IceCreamController">
    <children>
        <ComboBox fx:id="IceCreamType" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" />
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="IceCreamFlavor" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="142.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" />
        <CheckBox fx:id="S1" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="58.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Шоколад" />
        <CheckBox fx:id="S2" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="86.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Орехи" />
        <CheckBox fx:id="S3" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="114.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Джем" />
        <Button fx:id="ToOrder" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="179.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Заказать" />
      <ListView fx:id="Orders" layoutX="222.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="181.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="42.400000000000006" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="222.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="23.0" />
      <Label layoutX="124.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="39.0" text="Цена: " />
      <Label fx:id="Price" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="214.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="31.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Примечание: Я только учусь писать такие программы и в Java я тоже недавно. Поэтому если заметите ошибки и неформальности, пожалуйста напишите про них)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного не понял полного смысла да и кода в целом, так что надеюсь мои "слова" помогут. На самом деле есть несколько вариантов, к примеру:

Создай метод в контролере, для изменения текста кнопки и после каждого выбора (после кнопки окей или любого Action) вызывай этот метод и передавай тот тип мороженого который выбран.

Если будут трудности, могу добавить код, но это уже завтра и за надобностью